# If returns are correlated, are Sharpe ratios correlated?

Tags: correlation, sharpe-ratio

Suppose we have two correlated return series:
$$a \sim N(\mu_a,\sigma_a^2)$$
$$b \sim N(\mu_b,\sigma_b^2)$$
$$correl(a,b)=\rho$$

The sample Sharpe ratios of the two series, after $t$ samples for $t \to \infty$, are approximately distributed as:
$$\zeta_a \sim N(\frac {\mu_a} {\sigma_a}, \frac 1 t)$$
$$\zeta_b \sim N(\frac {\mu_b} {\sigma_b}, \frac 1 t)$$

But are the Sharpe ratios correlated?
$$correl(\zeta_a,\zeta_b)=?$$

Empirically, I found they are equally correlated:
$$correl(\zeta_a,\zeta_b)≈correl(a,b)$$

But what is the math behind?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but you are better off writing  $ \sqrt{t} \eta \sim N(\frac{\mu}{\sigma},1)$ for the sample sharpe ratios. If you want to keep the $t$ in the standard deviation then it should be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$ but that still goes to zero as $n \rightarrow \infty$ so its not a good idea to do that.

Comment: should be $t \rightarrow \infty$ in above.

Comment: Don't think there's a simple expression for it. Perhaps [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/539426/derivation-covariance-between-ratio-of-random-variables) on the covariance of two ratios of RV's might help.

Comment: An approximate normal form for the vector of Sharpe ratios of correlated assets is given in section 4.2 of my [Short Sharpe Course](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=3036276). See also eqn. (4.29) for the expansion when returns are elliptically distributed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Remark 1:* From the information in your question, I think you assumed that the risk free rate $r_f$ is equal to $0$ and the Sharp ratio is
> $$\frac{\mathbb{E}(a)-r_f}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(a)}} = \frac{\mathbb{E}(a)}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(a)}} $$ where $\mathbb{E}(a)$
> and $\mathbb{V}(a)$ are the expected value and variance of the return
> $a$.

Now, return to the question, for simplifying the problem, we assume that the variances of the two series are known (and equal to $\sigma_a^2$ and $\sigma_b^2$). Then
$$\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(a)}=\sigma_a$$
$$\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(b)}=\sigma_b$$

From $t$ return  samples $(a_i,b_i)_{i=1,..,t}$ of $(a,b)$, we can estimate the expected returns as
$$\mathbb{E}(a) = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t a_i$$
$$\mathbb{E}(b) = \frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t b_i$$

> *Remark 2*: we note that these $(a_i,b_i)$ and $(a_j,b_j)$ are
> independent if $i \ne j$ and for any $i$, there is a correlation
> $\rho$ between $a_i$ and $b_i$.

and so, their Sharpe ratio can be estimated as follows
$$\zeta_a=\frac{\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t a_i}{\sigma_a}$$
$$\zeta_b=\frac{\frac{1}{t}\sum_{i=1}^t b_i}{\sigma_b}$$

> *Remarque 3:* according the [central limit theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem#Classical_CLT),  $$\sqrt{t}\cdot \zeta_a  \xrightarrow{t\to+\infty} \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{\mu_a}{\sigma_a},1 \right)$$ Hence, your
> formula in the question should be some kind like this one  $$\zeta_a 
>  \xrightarrow{t\to+\infty} \mathcal{N}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}\frac{\mu_a}{\sigma_a},\frac{1}{t} \right)$$

Now, we compute the correlation between $\zeta_a$ and $\zeta_b$. It suffices to compute their covariance (their variance is known and equal to $\frac{1}{t}$ from the remark 3).

$$
\begin{align}
Cov(\zeta_a, \zeta_b) &= \frac{1}{t^2 \sigma_a \sigma_b} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq t}Cov(a_i,b_j) \\
&= \frac{1}{t^2 \sigma_a \sigma_b} \left(  \sum_{1 \leq i  \leq t}Cov(a_i,b_i)  +\underbrace{\sum_{1 \leq i \ne j \leq t}Cov(a_i,b_j)}_{=0 \text{ because of the independence according to remark } 2} \right) \\
&=\frac{1}{t^2 \sigma_a \sigma_b} \cdot t \cdot Cov(a,b)\\
&=\frac{1}{t^2 \sigma_a \sigma_b} \cdot t \cdot \rho \sigma_a \sigma_b\\
&=\frac{\rho}{t} 
\end{align}
$$

Finally, the correlation between the two Sharpe ratios is

$$\rho(\zeta_a,\zeta_b) = \frac{Cov(\zeta_a, \zeta_b)}{\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(\zeta_a)}\sqrt{\mathbb{V}(\zeta_b)}} =\color{red}{\rho }$$